# select data group by distinct date and get first and last data in the group

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, aggregate-functions

I am not sure if this is doable, i have a table of data with timestamp

e.g.

```
apple    2013-01-02 06:24:22
banana    2013-01-12 11:08:22
apple    2013-01-02 15:24:22
apple    2013-01-02 12:30:16
banana    2013-01-14 18:34:22
```

i want to:

1. rearrange the data base on distinct date not timetamp, means all same date will group together
2. if possible i hope to achieve the below in final result

   ```
   apple     2013-01-02 06:24:22  2013-01-02 15:24:22  // get first and last data
   banana    2013-01-12 11:08:22  2013-01-12 11:08:22  // only one data in the group
   banana    2013-01-14 18:34:22  2013-01-14 18:34:22  // only one data in the group
   ```

How can i do this with minimum sql queries instead of using a loop to determine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT fruitName, MIN(a.timestamp), MAX(a.timestamp)
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY DATE(a.timestamp), fruitName;
```

Comment: hi, any solution for part two? some groups may have 5-6 records, some may only have one

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

```
SELECT FRUIT_NAME, DATE(mydate) AS dateStamp FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DATE(TABLE.mydate);
```

Where:

FRUIT_NAME: your field for name

mydate your date field.

Comment: thanks, actually i am more concern on part two question, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you what you need. (Question's 2nd Part)

```
SELECT Fruit, Min(DateTime) AS FirstDateTime, Max(DateTime) AS LastDateTime FROM Table1 
GROUP BY DATE(DateTime);
```

This would give you the output

```
FRUIT      FIRSTDATETIME           LASTDATETTIME
apple     2013-01-02 06:24:22  2013-01-02 15:24:22
banana    2013-01-12 11:08:22  2013-01-12 11:08:22 
banana    2013-01-14 18:34:22  2013-01-14 18:34:22
```